# Jenkins War Deployment on Tomcat

Tags: jenkins, war, continuous-deployment

While Deploying my war on **Tomcat** server, I am getting  these issues.

> I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing
>   request: Software caused connection abort: socket write error [INFO]
>   Retrying request
>
> Failed to getClass for
>   org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.DeployMojo

Comment: Did you install  deploy container container?

Comment: Yes , I installed the deploy conyainer on my jenkins.